# Is Acceleration of Earth Constant in its Orbit around the Sun?

Tags: orbital-motion, satellites, escape-velocity

According to this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=velocity%20at%20the%20perigee&sxsrf=ALeKk02F_HIsIvFKngD-mN1ff3ibe5FVMQ:1621518048598&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi58qG6sdjwAhVmzTgGHcG3Ar8Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=913#imgrc=8Kp3s_TF_kiMlM) , we can say that the Earth's acceleration is constant as the path is circular. But how ?

Comment: Well, it isn’t actually purely circular.

Comment: Yeah , I agree with you .............. but I'm not able to imagine the scenario

Comment: Do you mean you can see no acceleration anywhere, or you cannot see how it has small irregularities in its orbit?

Comment: Acceleration is a vector quantity. Even for perfectly circular motion its direction is constantly changing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't overthink it, it's actually quite obvious that acceleration of the Earth is constant despite the path being slightly elliptical.

Though the exact path and velocity of the Earth through its orbit have slightly more complicated expressions, but as long as the distance of the earth to the sun doesn't change much, the magnitude of the acceleration will always be $\frac{GM}{R^2}$.

What **won't** be constant is not just the direction of the acceleration, but the amount that's in the tangential direction vs. radial direction due to the elliptical orbit. So it actually doesn't help us that much in the end that the magnitude of acceleration $|\vec{a}|$ is roughly constant.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Custer points out, the earths orbit is slightly elliptical (the semi-minor axis, is 99.98% of the semi-major axis), but the differences are low enough to assume that it is approximately circular.
For an object to travel a circular path the magnitude of the acceleration has to be constant, and is directed towards the centre of the circle.

you can show this because if you have an object moving in a circular path (of radius $1$, for simplicity) with angular speed $w$, then its position $\underline{r}$ is .

$$\underline{r}=cos(wt)\widehat{\underline{x}}+sin(wt)\widehat{\underline{y}}$$
which if differentiate, to get the velocity
$$\underline{v}=w(-sin(wt)\widehat{\underline{x}}+cos(wt)\widehat{\underline{y}})$$
and differentiate again to get the acceleration
$$\underline{a}=-w^2(cos(wt)\widehat{\underline{x}}+sin(wt)\widehat{\underline{y}})$$
which has magnitude $w^2$, and is directed opposite to the direction of the position vector, ie. towards the centre of the circle

hopefully that helps

Answer (score -1):

It's not moving in a circular path it's moving in a corkscrew like motion because the sun is traveling 490,000 mph is what we're told. So that's not circular so this is an incorrect assumption according to the heliocentric model itself